# formula to give next month and end date?

Tags: calculated-column-formula

Not sure if this is possible,

i have a set of given dates, and i want to an extra column to increase the given date by 13 months, is this possible?

e.g 16/02/2016 ===> 31/03/2017

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example

> e.g 16/02/2016 ===> 31/03/2017

is:

- Add one year
- Add one month
- Set last day of that month

To get the last day of the month, substract one day from next months first day.
Since DAYs count by whole numbers; that is daynumber 0 (of next month, so to get your 13 months add 2 months )

**Formula [MyDate]:**

```
=IF(
    NOT(
        ISBLANK( [Due Date] )
       )
    ,DATE(
            YEAR   ( [Due Date] ) + 1
          , MONTH( [Due Date] ) + 2
          , 0
         )
    ,[Due Date]
   )
```

[image]

***Optional***

Since SharePoint counts DAYs by whole numbers (*and not a TIMESTAMP like JavaScript does*)
you have to add a time notation with fractions.

```
=[MyDate]+.5     is 12:00
=[MyDate]+1/24   is 01:00
```

---

**All Formulas and Examples that do work in SP:**
http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List